# Animate a magazine from InDesign

Tags: adobe-indesign, publishing, adobe-edge-animate

I'm sorry if the title doesn't make much sense.

Basically my colleague has finished designing and published a magazine for our client. Our client has asked us to have the magazine viewable on web pages. They want to have certain layers animate and have transition effects between pages.

Is there an easy/efficient way off achieving this from an InDesign file. We are looking at using Adobe Edge. Could we open the DPS file in Edge and then begin to build an interactive, animating magazine?

Many Thanks,
Peter

Comment: You might try zmags. As a reader I hate it, but it probably does what your client wants.

Comment: For what purpose does the client want it?

Comment: @Joonas they want to bring their (printed) magazine (designed in InDesign) and publish it on their website, with some objects/layers animating.

Comment: Have you considered using Adobe Publish Online?

Answer (score 1):

The fastest solution for this would be [the SWF export option from InDesign](https://helpx.adobe.com/indesign/using/interactive-web-documents-flash.html#create_interactive_swf_flash_files_for_the_web). But maybe you don't want to use flash with modern web devices in mind. There are other solutions like [issuu.com](http://issuu.com).

Comment: This isn't really what I am after

Answer (score 1):

I have created a platform to do this. It is called [Without Coding](https://withoutcoding.com). It requires you to export your artwork to images/layers which you can turn into animated objects very easily.

Answer (score -3):

If it's a magazine, the best way to present it on the web is by using flipbook. Modern flipbook readers are in html5 and allow you to add anything the can be added on websites. Animations, videos, transactions, audio, social network widgets, etc.

Comment: I suppose this is not just an angle to sell / promote a Flipbook creation service, in which case you'd expand your answer to demonstrate the solution rather than ask to chat.

Comment: How does this answer the question about using Adobe Edge? Downvoted since I don't see that it does.